# How can I Use LogiXML Analysis Grid in ASP.Net?

Tags: charts, reporting, adhoc

Hope you all are fine. I am a beginner in BI Reporting. I need to know that how can I use LogiXML Analysis Grid in ASP.Net application with my own data.

Hope to get replies from you.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be more specific as to how you would like to use the Analysis Grid within your ASP.NET application?

The Analysis Grid is a super-element within the LogiXML Logi Info product, that allows you to connect to a data source and display an interactive grid within an dynamic HTML output.   For some details, you may want to visit some of the online docs:

Working with Analysis Grids

> http://www.logixml.com/devnet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1037&dnProd=&IdeDisplayStatus=Collapsed

If you need some details about connecting with your data sources you can create any number of different types of data connections, here is some additional documentation on building connections:

Introducing Data Connections

> http://www.logixml.com/devnet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1146&dnProd=&IdeDisplayStatus=Collapsed

To allow for integration with your current ASP.NET application, you may be asking about a security integration with single-sign on, so that you can pass credentials from your existing application into the Analysis Grid report.   Here are some docs about that:

Introducing Logi Security

> http://www.logixml.com/devnet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1205&dnProd=&IdeDisplayStatus=Collapsed

Working with Logi Secure Key

> http://www.logixml.com/devnet/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1126&dnProd=&IdeDisplayStatus=Collapsed

hope this information helps.

Comment: I want to use logiXML Analysis Grid in My ASP.Net application for Adhoc Reporting. Can I use That?